# Type 'Key' cannot be used to index type when mapping type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to transform the following type into a more managable structure and filter out some parameters.

```ts
interface components {
  schemas: {
    CheckPriceBooking: {
      EventId: number;
    };
    CheckPriceResult: {
      TotalPriceIncVat: number;
    };
    PostBooking: {
      EventId: number;
      Whatever: number;
    };
    BookingCreated: {
      BookingId: number;
    };
    ErrorResponse: {
      Message?: string | null;
      ErrorMessages?: string[] | null;
    };
  };
}

interface paths {
  '/v1/Booking/CheckPrice': {
    post: {
      requestBody?: {
        content: {
          'text/json': components['schemas']['CheckPriceBooking'];
          'application/*+json': components['schemas']['CheckPriceBooking'];
        }
      };
      responses: {
        200: {
          content: {
            'application/json': components['schemas']['CheckPriceResult'];
            'text/json': components['schemas']['CheckPriceResult'];
          };
        };
        400: {
          content: {
            "text/json": components["schemas"]["ErrorResponse"];
          };
        };
      }
    };
    get: {
      requestBody?: {
        content: {
          'text/json': components['schemas']['CheckPriceBooking'];
          'application/*+json': components['schemas']['CheckPriceBooking'];
        }
      };
      responses: {
        200: {
          content: {
            'application/json': components['schemas']['CheckPriceResult'];
            'text/json': components['schemas']['CheckPriceResult'];
          };
        };
      }
    }
  }
  "/v1/Booking": {
    post: {
      requestBody?: {
        content: {
          "text/json": components["schemas"]["PostBooking"];
          "application/*+json": components["schemas"]["PostBooking"];
        };
      };
      responses: {
        201: {
          content: {
            "text/json": components["schemas"]["BookingCreated"];
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
}
```

I've managed to write this but it throws a ts error. The type usage works, but the mapping fails. [Here's the ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgQewLYAc0guAZ2QG8BYAKGWQIQAsIM4CAuEiqqgYXoQGsAFKMCQAhNGl6gA5qzKUOVAKIA3fGACSAE1YgArhgBG0ANzsOAX1PyuPAUKQAlCAV0AbMLLMKAKmjBxXQWEIdRAEADU4D2Q9QxMvZEsE-jQCMDEJaU9rDhU1LR19IygrBSoAdVooiFUoQriShKScjMkQKU4oCGrtNhyqVukCmKL4nOaFRSgoNCgnAhwQAghssuQAWWcCOCkIAH5WNKF25AAfEddXUrKpmahNgm3dggPqMGOpAG0AXTOLq6a12a5goFFAkFgiBQWCitCIcioAHIAPTKACMyMG7WR3AgfCCSERqw4ODSxIUXQAjrpnOk0JoAJ6vBFrVC4SDgcmsxGQAAeYGRACsCLgiWzsLg1ARPoiaPRGAREd8Zbj8fYIFipErrqzkIi4FgsK5hFFgLhkQAqADUwtFrHQErwhBlcoYTCVKtsBI14jaWu%20OrKIP6iUDVC6C1wyxYfV1ACYAAwJrlrdDgNQp7kGo0msBmkBCkUgMUOxZSl10N2K5WI1V2YLzNxgbUJXU8iD8wt28Vl52yysKj21r3qxvuFshhQTVnTtYAFiTmYUaY50RZuqoACI%20QLbSBN-bML2wNLN66FZvlZvbrN5otlpew0Gn1RZxZAQldmvW8gqTS0mIjLMj%20VArhmsYbu2nZ7iWR6Sn257ujWdbepqE4bnq2bGggprmtaMGHo65b9vKSGeni9aiL60joTOP5vuGzj3s4S7IImyYQbqYGcpxkFYbm%20ZdsWhHHtKJFVkOKGjs4Ta0RhUG7kWsFEQhA5kcOFHemOzYBiBFgvqG9FNGYwZbqiGKagevGkt%20IZ-rSgFMqx3G2Rh24dopuBWaW8Enp8Z5qQQl7%20SkAHUe0j56Vu-E4XmeE2kW3lwU6fkBaRQVXqFdKZBFumToZIYMb%20TFRixvEKImaKsaB7LgeuG7udBiUib5p6IRl-map03SQJokX5a%20BlFW%2007AqC5BgAyWAoFl-CwgQAA83jIB5%20CaEQMJgHCyAALzIJtcIAHy7RBnwANLIKAyC8BADJoDAyDLUwj3nb8q0gOtJD7ak0S6CAvAgGgADuICJMgezIBdOg1NA3xcvZZLIE41LAF0mhLa9Mo2Uqh0ygjdKMkOLlDjuQm0cGzQUGmaTIAY9IMqws3zTK5mYuF-p4xA1K0kqJ0snk4DDGiAA0ZiVNUtSsHGFCU%20Q42Wha43qMgQNwOAyBgGgyCMiAcAYCalwMhrUBqwQMCzBgyAAAYHQQVsa1rW0oOblzA9IbxQLoCBgLoXTMONk3TcgTNbUQe0sii6JszlUg4iOwRivV%20MtSlYntZJ8dUTHcnFZGSwrOVbxRLoMYLgmT504yKflmlVbBde0y3iV%20f9VOfz1VQaTFzG7EV-T1eqelGeadJLjjnlU4mdcm6s5Z8Nc-%200Q%20an-ntfXWWWRPHARsxmZdz7pdJn3Vc9q1q%20BfXN5zM3D5b6%207c-vvJdSwmaLHwzp8r7XF5Xl1XQ9K3d88hgRWAoBaZEQA). At the bottom of the playground you can also find the structure I am looking to transform the types into.

```ts
type PostPaths<T extends paths = paths> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends { post: unknown } ? K : never]: {
    request: Required<T[K]['post']>['requestBody']['content']['text/json']; // <- Type cannot be used to index type
  }
};

// This works?
const body: PostPaths['/v1/Booking']['request'] = {
  EventId: 1,
  Whatever: 2
};
```

Comment: This is a bug/limitation in TS documented at [ms/TS#21760](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760) (which is specifically written about multiple generics but the same lack of constraint happens whenever you start using non-generic indices *after* a generic one.) See the linked q/a for more info and some workarounds. For this deeply nested type I'd probably just use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/m0VvOw).